# SocketIO server on Android/IOS/Windows Mobile?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, socket.io, windows-mobile

I'd like a way to deploy a socketIO server as an app on mobile.
Ideally, the solution is cross-platform.
Also, I'm not married to socketIO---it can be something similar like `sockjs`.

I've looked into jxcore with the cordova plugin. Unfortunately, it doesn't work with it, as per https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore-cordova/issues/103
Most search results are about running a socketIO *client*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I confirmed that socketIO doesn't work out-of-the-box with jxcore. If I'm not mistaken, you have to compile it for the device.

On the other hand, I was able to create a working sockjs server Android app using jxcore and it's cordova plugin. Basically, I adapted the `express_sample` to use the sockjs "hello world" example.

Investigating `sockjs` a little more, I found that it has similar performance to SocketIO. (See http://mrjoes.github.io/2011/12/15/sockjs-bench.html.) It also has the same multi-browser support. (See https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client#supported-transports-by-browser-html-served-from-http-or-https) If I'm not  mistaken, the same transport support let's it run well across different Mobile browsers. So this looks like the winner.